# Retrieve theme from WordPress Store

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

Good morning,

I have a new client who has been working with an overseas developer and they seem to have simply disappeared. We have tried numerous times to contact them, and I am thinking it is possible something happened to them personally as the site they were working on for the client is still up - and they're nowhere to be found.

The goal was to continue the work they started, as it does seem somewhat extensive - rather than starting fresh. I understand this may sound ridiculous, and apologize for wasting everyone's time if this is simply impossible..

**Premise:** the site uses wordpress, with the woo-commerce plugin installed - both of which I've used in the past. I have a new wordpress blog and woo-commerce setup for the "new site".

I've been unable to successfully retrieve whatever custom CSS they've written for this, and have really only been able to retrieve the rendered code.

**Underlying question**:Does anyone have any suggestions for retrieving what has been done on this site, or somehow extracting the work as a theme? We have zero ability to log in to this site via FTP or via the wordpress login. My guess is that I'll have to start the project over from scratch, which naturally would be very disappointing to the client as I am trying to save them some money.

Site in question: http://olshop.filgap.com // http://olshop.filgap.com/shop

Comment: view-source:http://olshop.filgap.com/ you will see all the css files listed and you can access them (also the js files). you can copy all the rendered html by viewing the source on each page but you will have to code the theme files and templates with php.

Comment: @David unfortunately, when I view the source for the CSS files - I'm presented with the top of the standard wordpress CSS file, but not below it. I even made a cute little workaround HTML page to download the file directly - no dice. Does not include the actual CSS properties.

Comment: there are a lot of stylesheets you need to look through them all, the main.css file affects some of the page. The developer obviously used the twenty15 theme as a template but didnt use the stylesheet and added a new one. http://olshop.filgap.com/wp-content/themes/newyork/css/main.css

Comment: @David you are actually right. Not sure how I missed that. Submit this as an answer you certainly should get the credit...

Comment: dont worry about it :)